# Android testing: is it correct implement "for Loop" in tests with Espresso?

Tags: android, loops, android-espresso

I'm not sure that it is correct implement "for loop" in tests with Espresso. I want to test first child of all parents in ExpandableListView. 
The potential code:

```
for(i = 0; i < length; i++){
onData(anything())
    .inAdapterView(withId(R.id.userProfileActivityList))
    .atPosition(i)
    .check(matches(isDisplayed()))
    .perform(click())
    .check(matches(hasDescendant(isDisplayed())));
}
```

Thanks a lot.

Comment: General rule of thumb for test is one assert per method. In case you want to create an array and validate the same against another set of values then it is fine. What exactly are you trying to test it against though?

Comment: Hello, thanks for reply. Actually I want to test that each uniform parent is clickable and displayed, and each parent has uniform child which is displayed too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Of course, why not?  There are two thoughts I have on this.

A: What you've done is fine, good style, results in less code re-use etc.

B: I sometimes prefer code verbosity in test cases, for the sake of clarity of results.  When my test cases fail, I want to know exactly why they failed, so I can quickly go back to my code and fix them.  This is also the motivation of the "one assert per method" concept.

Think this: When this test case fails is it going to fail in a way that guides the developer to the proper functionality with clarity and ease?

If the answer to this question is yes, what else matters?  Granted, this encompasses a lot!  Maintaining generically good coding style in your test cases, good assertions with solid messages, and ensuring your asserts are placed to provide solid stack traces... just to name a few!

Comment: Thanks, it is good point. I haven't thought about what if test failed and consequences to solve the problem. How we could know what/whose functionality failed exactly ? Parents, childs?  I will reconsider this loop)